# TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined error after doing npm run build

Tags: node.js, path, vuejs2, webpack-4, vue-cli-3

I'm new to webpack and want to use html-critical-webpack-plugin in my vue.config.js file which is created by vue-cli3. But I get this error while using const path= require('path') in my vue.config.js file. I don't see any webpack.config.js file in my root folder. How do I get this working in vue.config.js file?

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlCriticalPlugin = require("html-critical-webpack-plugin");
const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin')
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      new VuetifyLoaderPlugin(),
      new HtmlCriticalPlugin({
        base: path.join(path.resolve(__dirname), 'dist/'),
        src: 'index.html',
        dest: 'index.html',
        inline: true,
        minify: true,
        extract: true,
        width: 375,
        height: 565,
        penthouse: {
          blockJSRequests: false,
        }
      })
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true,
  },
  lintOnSave: false,
  pwa: {
    // configure the workbox plugin
    workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',
    workboxOptions: {
      // swSrc is required in InjectManifest mode.
      swSrc: 'src/service-worker.js'
    }
  }
}
```